# Random number generator for g77

Tags: random, gfortran, g77

I'm currently using a Fortran code that uses:

```
double precision random 
random()
```

here is a sample code showing what random number generator I'm trying to work with:

```
  program rand
  M=128

  do j=1,M
  r=random()
  write(*,*)j,r
  end do

  stop
  end
```

However, using g77 or gfortran to compile on a mac, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_random_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccqbVarp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there a similar random number generator I can use when compiling with g77 or gfortran? Please note: I do not usually use Fortran, I am simply trying to compile someone else's Fortran 77 code! Thanks in advance for any advice or help.

Comment: I am not a fortron coder still looking at error it seems that you are missing some library.

Comment: use random_number, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by including:

```
 integer, parameter :: seed = 86456
 call srand(seed)
```

And then using rand().